# How to upload 2 files from 2 different input into database with php

Tags: php, file, file-upload, image-upload

I'm trying to upload 2 files from 2 separate inputs. I'm able to upload and get a success message by uploading one file but now I need to upload 2 files to the database and I don't know how to do it if it becomes 2 files. am I suppose the repeat the code twice to upload 2 files? or is there an easy way to do so. 
Here is my code:

```
//EMPLOYEE:Add

if(isset($_POST['emp_addbtn']))
{
    $emp_name=$_POST['emp_name'];
    $emp_dob=$_POST['emp_dob'];
    $emp_gender=$_POST['emp_gender'];
    $emp_nat=$_POST['emp_nat'];
    $emp_phone=$_POST['emp_phone'];
    $emp_email=$_POST['emp_email'];
    $emp_curr_add=$_POST['emp_curr_add'];
    $emp_perm_add=$_POST['emp_perm_add'];
    $s_id=$_POST['s_id'];
    $c_id=$_POST['c_id'];
    $emp_start_date=$_POST['emp_start_date'];
    $emp_as=$_POST['emp_as'];
    $emp_job_id=$_POST['emp_job_id'];
    $emp_end_date=$_POST['emp_end_date'];
    $emp_status=$_POST['emp_status'];

    $contact_person=$_POST['contact_person'];
    $rlt=$_POST['rlt'];
    $emer_phone =$_POST['emer_phone '];
    $emer_email=$_POST['emer_email'];

    $bank_name=$_POST['bank_name'];
    $acc_name=$_POST['acc_name'];
    $acc_num=$_POST['acc_num'];


    $pass_no=$_POST['pass_no'];
    $arrival=$_POST['arrival'];
    $pass_expiry=$_POST['pass_expiry'];
    $pass_status=$_POST['pass_status'];
    $visa_type=$_POST['visa_type'];
    $visa_issued=$_POST['visa_issued'];
    $visa_expiry=$_POST['visa_expiry'];

    $emp_img=$_FILES['emp_img'];
    $img_name=$_FILES['emp_img']['name'];
    $img_tmpName=$_FILES['emp_img']['tmp_name'];
    $img_size=$_FILES['emp_img']['size'];
    $img_error=$_FILES['emp_img']['error'];
    $img_type=$_FILES['emp_img']['type'];

            $imgExt=explode('.', $img_name);
            $imgActualExt= strtolower(end($imgExt));

            //files allows to upload

            $img_allow=array('jpg','jpeg','png');

        if(in_array($imgActualExt, $img_allow))
        {

            if($img_error === 0)
            {
                if($img_size < 10000000)
                {

                //  $docNewName= uniqid('',true).".".$docActualExt;
                    $imgDestination='emp_upload/'.$img_name;
                    move_uploaded_file($img_tmpName, $imgDestination);


                    $query="INSERT INTO employee (emp_name,emp_dob,emp_gender,emp_national,emp_phone,emp_email,emp_curr_add,emp_perm_add,s_id,c_id,emp_start,emp_as,emp_job_id,emp_end,emp_status,contact_person,rlt,emer_phone,emer_email,bank_name,acc_name,acc_num,emp_img) 
                                        VALUES ('$emp_name','$emp_dob','$emp_gender','$emp_nat','$emp_phone','$emp_email','$emp_curr_add','$emp_perm_add','$s_id','$c_id','$emp_start_date','$emp_as','$emp_job_id','$emp_end_date','$emp_status','$contact_person','$rlt','$emer_phone','$emer_email','$bank_name','$acc_name','$acc_num','$img_name')";
                    $query_run=mysqli_query($conn,$query);

                        if($query_run)
                        {

                            $query2="INSERT INTO passport (pass_no,e_id,arrival,pass_expiry,pass_status,visa_type,visa_issued,visa_expiry) 
                                                    VALUES ('$pass_no',LAST_INSERT_ID(),'$arrival','$pass_expiry','$pass_status','$visa_type','$visa_issued','$pass_expiry')";
                            $query_run2=mysqli_query($conn,$query2);
                            if ($query_run2)
                            {
                                $_SESSION['success']="New Employee Has Been Added";
                                header('Location: employee.php');

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $_SESSION['status']="Error on passport";
                                header('Location: employee.php');
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                        $_SESSION['status']="New Employee  Has NOT Been Added";
                        header('Location: employee.php');
                        }
                    }
                    else
                        {
                            $_SESSION['status']="The file is too big!";
                            header('Location: addemp2.php');

                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $_SESSION['status']="Error uploading file";
                            header('Location: addemp2.php');
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    $_SESSION['status']="Wrong type of image";
                            header('Location: addemp2.php');
                }
```

Comment: There is no improvement since you asked this question last time. As far as I can see, you don't upload your files to a database which makes the question quite confusing

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli also contains good examples of writing safe SQL using mysqli. Parameterising your queries will also greatly reduce the risk of accidental syntax errors as a result of un-escaped input values.

Comment: Anyway if you want to read another, then repeat all the code which reads from the $_FILES array, but using the name of the second input, and repeat the tests to see if it's valid, and make sure they're all valid before proceeding to the database inserts. Or you could do this using a loop through the $_FILES array (rather than referencing specific entries by name), so then it won't really matter how many files are being uploaded.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I've solved the previous issue and this is a new question on how to do it for multiple files.